# Python iterating/look up dictionary unexpected behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem when I try to look up data in a csv dictionary. A list of dates and times are in one csv and it should look up the data to specific date and time in second csv. I look for an exact match and 22 next records. The problem is that it only fetch for first date and time and rest is not found even though I can see it's there. I feel like this has a very easy solution, but I can't think anything. It must be a problem in my iteration code.

Code:

```
import csv
csv_eph = open("G:\\db.csv")
csv_reader_eph = csv.reader(csv_eph, delimiter=",")
csv_dict_eph = csv.DictReader (csv_eph)
csv_matches = open("G:\\query.csv")
csv_reader_matches = csv.reader(csv_matches, delimiter=",")
csv_dict_matches = csv.DictReader (csv_matches)

result = []
var = 0
for row in csv_dict_matches:
    datum = row["Date"]
    cas = row["Time"]
    result.append('\n')
    result.append(row)
    for eph in csv_dict_eph:
        if str(eph["datum"]) == str(datum) and str(eph["cas"]) == str(cas):
            var = 23 
        if var > 0:
            result.append(eph)
            var = var - 1

with open("G:\\compiled.txt", "w") as output:
    for item in result:
        output.write(str(item))
        output.write('\n')
```

SOLUTION!
I implemented  jasonharper solution and it works flawlesly, many thanks. It was indeed problem with end of dictionary. Now fixed it looks like this and works like intended:

```
import csv
csv_eph = open("G:\\db.csv")
csv_reader_eph = csv.reader(csv_eph, delimiter=",")
csv_dict_eph = csv.DictReader (csv_eph)
csv_matches = open("G:\\query.csv")
csv_reader_matches = csv.reader(csv_matches, delimiter=",")
csv_dict_matches = csv.DictReader (csv_matches)

#jasonharper
eph_list = []
for eph in csv_dict_eph:
    eph_list.append(eph)


print (eph_list)
result = []
var = 0
for row in csv_dict_matches:
    print (row)
    datum = row["Date"]
    cas = row["Time"]
    result.append('\n')
    result.append(row)
    for eph in eph_list:
        if str(eph["datum"]) == str(datum) and str(eph["cas"]) == str(cas):
            var = 23 
        if var > 0:
            result.append(eph)
            var = var - 1

with open("G:\\compiled.txt", "w") as output:
    for item in result:
        output.write(str(item))
        output.write('\n')
```

Comment: You are iterating over `csv_dict_eph` multiple times, once for each row in `csv_dict_matches`.  After the first iteration, you're at the end of the CSV file, and no further rows will be returned.  You either need to open that file inside the loop, so that you get a fresh DictReader object each time, or read the whole thing into a list at the start of a code (the list can then be iterated as many times as you want).

Comment: We can't help if we can't see your data.

Answer (score 3):

i believe changing:

```
csv_dict_eph = csv.DictReader (csv_eph)
```

to:

```
csv_dict_eph = list(csv.DictReader(csv_eph))
```

will fix the problem.